# custom sql queries in JPA Criteria Predicate, StringPath, Querydsl

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I have a Spring boot project with hibernate 5.4.12, Java 11 and Postgres.

I am trying to build a custom Sort/Filter mechanism using JPA and Querydsl, [here](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-querydsl) is one blog for reference.

We have a gin index column which is used for full text search feature by postgres. In jpa repository, I can query the column easily as below

```
@Query(value = "select * from products where query_token @@ plainto_tsquery(:query)", nativeQuery = true)
Page<Product> findAllByTextSearch(@Param("query") String query, Pageable pageable);
```

I am aware that fts queries are not yet supported by JPA criteria or querydsl APIs (I may be wrong). Since normal filtering logic will go through criteria API, how do add fts capabilities in criteria API? Is there a way to add custom native query as predicate or StringPath or any other Qtype paths?

**UPDATE**

My `SearchPredicate` class

```
public class SearchPredicate<E extends Enum<E>> {

  private SearchCriteria<E> searchCriteria;

  public <T> BooleanExpression getPredicate(Class<T> entityClass, String entityName) {
    PathBuilder<T> entityPath = new PathBuilder<>(entityClass, entityName);

    switch (searchCriteria.getPathType()) {
      case String:
        StringPath stringPath = entityPath.getString(searchCriteria.getKey());
        return stringPath.eq(searchCriteria.getStringValue());

      case Enum:
        return entityPath.getEnum(searchCriteria.getKey(), searchCriteria.getEnumClass())
            .eq(Enum.valueOf(searchCriteria.getEnumClass(), searchCriteria.getStringValue()));

      case Float:
        NumberPath<Float> floatPath = entityPath.getNumber(searchCriteria.getKey(), Float.class);
        Float floatValue = Float.parseFloat(searchCriteria.getStringValue());
        return floatPath.eq(floatValue);

      case Integer:
        NumberPath<Integer> integerPath = entityPath.getNumber(searchCriteria.getKey(), Integer.class);
        Integer integerValue = Integer.parseInt(searchCriteria.getStringValue());
        return integerPath.eq(integerValue);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

My `SearchCriteria` class

```
public class SearchCriteria<E extends Enum<E>> {
  private String key;
  private Object value;
  private PathType pathType;
  private Class<E> enumClass;

  public String getStringValue() {
    return value.toString();
  }
}
```

And My `PathType` Enum

```
public enum PathType {
  String, Enum, Integer, Float;
}
```

On these same lines, I am assuming/expecting something for text search as well e.g.

```
case Search:
  FtsPath ftsPath = entityPath.getFtsPath("query_token");
  return ftsPath.search("some search string")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should first make the `@@` operator available by registering a custom function for your ORM. Then you can do `plainto_tsquery(query_token, :query)` in your JPQL query. How to register a custom function depends on the ORM you use. Assuming you use Hibernate, you're probably best of using the `MetadataContributor` SPI because functions registered through the `Dialect` have less flexibility with regard to the underlying SQL rendering AFAIK.

Then, if you want to use this in QueryDSL, you'd have to create a custom `Operator` and register a `Template` for that `Operator` in a subclass of `JPQLTemplates`. Alternatively, you can bypass the `Operation` expressions using a simple `TemplateExpression`: `Expressions.booleanTemplate("plainto_tsquery({0}, {1})", QProduct.product.queryToken, query)`, which returns a predicate.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It does look promising, however, it is kinda theoretical. I am fairly new to the framework and not familiar with the classes and features you mentioned above. Grateful, if you can explain it with some implementation. Also, your line `Alternatively, you can bypass...`, is it a different solution or just an extension of what explained earlier? Because, it would be best if it can be solved just by `Template`, without registering anything. (FYI, I am using hibernate)

Comment: You are using a mix of three frameworks here plus a database vendor specific dialect functions. That makes cooking up an entire example rather difficult. If you share you're code, I can post the required changes. However, for the QueryDSL part:  expressions (which operations are) are rendered to JPQL fragments using "Templates". You either define a template for a newly added operator in the templates you use, or you bypass the templates by using a template expression, which basically is a fragment of JPQL with some basic variable substitution.

Comment: I have added few classes of what I have implemented so far for your reference. Hope it helps. Also, added a pseudo code case statement as what would be an ideal implementation.